# Best way to search for a query in a JSON object using Python

Tags: python, json, search

[This is the problem description that I am tackling for one of my tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDm9y.png)
I need to create an appropriate document storage system which is highly efficient. While I have been tackling this using Python and trying to parse through the JSON like string by treating it as a dictionary. I am unsure of what am I doing wrong because it seems like there is a better way to do this. I just wanted to try to understand if there is a better way to do this and if there is, how do I go about it?
There are about 5000-10000 different JSON objects that are stored and more than 1000 queries which are fired to GET or DELETE something present in the storage.

This is my approach

```
import json
import sys
store = []

def getData(target):
    for data in store:
        flag=True
        for k,v in target.items():
            if isinstance(v,dict):
                return getData(v)
                continue
            elif isinstance(v, list):
                for i in v:
                    if i not in data["list"]:
                        flag = False
                        continue
            elif data.get(k) != v:
                flag = False
                continue
        if flag:
            print(json.dumps(data,separators=(',', ':')))
    return True
    

def deleteData(value):
    for data in store:
        flag = True
        for k, v in value.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                for i_k, i_v in v.items():
                    if data[k].get(i_k) != i_v:
                        flag = False
                        continue
            elif isinstance(v, list):
                for i in v:
                    if i not in data["list"]:
                        flag = False
                        continue
            elif data.get(k) != v:
                flag = False
                continue
        if flag and data in store:
            store.remove(data)


def parseInput():
    for command in sys.stdin:
        if not command:
            return
        operation, value = command.split(" ",maxsplit=1)
        objects = json.loads(value)
        if operation == 'add':
            store.append(objects)
        elif operation == 'get':
            getData(objects)
        elif operation == 'delete':
            deleteData(objects)
        else:
            return
  
parseInput()
```

INPUT:

```
add {"id":1,"last":"Doe","first":"John","location":{"city":"Oakland","state":"CA","postalCode":"94607"},"active":true}
add {"id":2,"last":"Doe","first":"Jane","location":{"city":"San Francisco","state":"CA","postalCode":"94105"},"active":true}
add {"id":3,"last":"Black","first":"Jim","location":{"city":"Spokane","state":"WA","postalCode":"99207"},"active":true}
add {"id":4,"last":"Frost","first":"Jack","location":{"city":"Seattle","state":"WA","postalCode":"98204"},"active":false}
get {"location":{"state":"WA"},"active":true}
get {"id":1}
get {"active":true}
delete {"active":true}
get {}
```

OUTPUT:

```
{"id":3,"last":"Black","first":"Jim","location":{"city":"Spokane","state":"WA","postalCode":"99207"},"active":true}
{"id":1,"last":"Doe","first":"John","location":{"city":"Oakland","state":"CA","postalCode":"94607"},"active":true}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please dont use recursion in the concept of api or website..

Comment: Just store the json object by loading the string..

Comment: Initially I didn't but to traverse the nested dictionaries, I figured I would have to use it. I didn't get you. Load the string? I am doing that, right? For GET, I would have to use the object though.

Comment: For what purpose are you using recursion?

Comment: to go through a nested dictionary. There can be 'n' nested dictionaries to traverse so to search in those, I use recursion @NanthakumarJJ

Comment: What about loops?